# confirm user wants to call a phone number after click

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to show a pop up that asks if the user wants to call the number when the user clicks on a number.

How do I do that? Currently, when I click on the number, it calls it automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a UIAlertView with the delegate set to self, and if the selectedButtonIndex is the buttonIndex of the yes button in the alert, call the number, if not, don't call the number.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Do you want to call..." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"No" otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
[alert setTag:02];
[alert show];
[alert release];

- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

    if (alertView.tag == 02 && buttonIndex != alertView.cancelButtonIndex) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://phonenumber"]];
    }
}
```

Comment: the setTag method really isn't needed unless you are using multiple UIAlertViews and I would change the message to just be the phone number like how Apple handles this when you tap a phone number in UIWebView and use Cancel and Call for the button titles.

Comment: Its up to the developer not you.

Answer (score 10):

You can also do:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"telprompt:0123456789"]];
```

to get the prompt and return to your app afterwards.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're looking for is something like what UIWebView does automatically to phone numbers.  It will pop a UIAlertView to ask if the user would like to call the number before dialing out.  To do that, make your class a UIAlertViewDelegate and do the following:

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle: nil
                            message: phonenum
                            delegate: self
                            cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                            otherButtonTitles:@"Call",nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

In addition, add the following method to the same class:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 0) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"tel://%@", phoneNum]]];
    }
}
```

The alert view will call back to this method when the user interacts with it.  The buttonIndex == 0  ensures that you only call the number when the user hits the Call button.

Comment: The "Call" button here came in as buttonIndex == 1, "Cancel" got 0. (And the strings need to be localized :) Thanks for this!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the UIAlertView method. 
The documentation is provided in [this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html) . I would suggest that you have a look at that documentation and everything is self explanatory.

But you may require something like this.

```
UIAlertView *alert = [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Really call?" message:@"Do you want to call this number?" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:nil] autorelease];
// optional - add more buttons:
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Yes"];
[alert show];
```