# To make a phone after click the alertView

Tags: iphone

Can i make 2 different button with alert and go to call 2 different phone number in the view?
I find a answer that it can do it on one button. but when i make other button, those will be go to same phone number! How do I do that? Thanks a lot!

[confirm user wants to call a phone number after click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154758/confirm-user-wants-to-call-a-phone-number-after-click)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Specify different numbers in the tel URL for each button, say  @"tel://1234" & @"tel://5678".

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Articles/PhoneLinks.html